# how to get "something" from <em>something</em> use java Regular expressions

Tags: java, html, regex

in the following, i need to get:

```
String regex = "Item#: <em>.*</em>";
String content = "xxx Item#: <em>something</em> yyy";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content); 

if( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

it will print:

```
Item#: <em>something</em>
```

but i just need the value "something".

i know i can use .substring(begin,end) to get the value,
but is there another way which would be more elegant?

Comment: [Parsing HTML the Ctulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: Other than that simply `"Item#: <em>(.*)</em>"` add brackets.

Comment: @soulseekah and make the regex non greedy `Item#: <em>(.*?)</em>`

Comment: @jlordo yep, non-greedy works much-much better :)

Comment: @jlordo, i can see the non greedy way much better. by checking [oracle docs regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints the whole string because you have printed it. `matcher.group()` prints the complete match. To get specific part of your matched string, you need to change your Regex to capture the content between the tag in a group: -

```
String regex = "Item#: <em>(.*?)</em>";
```

Also, use `Reluctant` quantifier`(.*?)` to match the least number of characters before an `</em>` is encountered.

And then in if, print `group(1)` instead of `group()`

```
if( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Anyways, you should not use `Regex` to parse `HTML`. Regex is not strong enough to achieve this task. You should probably use some `HTML` parser like - `HTML Cleaner`. Also see the link that is provided in one of the comments in the OP. That post is very nice explanation of the problems you can face.

Comment: wouldn't the reluctant quantifier be safer in this case? `"Item#: <em>(.*?)</em>"`